# Tomcat 8 Hangs. Requests are still coming in, but no responses are sent back

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, freeze, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat 8.0.14 (recently upgraded from Tomcat 5.5) and am experiencing very inconsistent hanging of the application server.

- When a hang occurs, attempting to navigate to any page causes an infinite wait
- Tomcat is running as a windows service and the service is still running but must be restarted to get the application back online. I've looked at the network traffic and it appears that tomcat is receiving requests, but not generating any responses.
- When a hang occurs, all of the http-nio threads are waiting to get a Connection to the database. This is probably the causes of the previous point due to all threads in a waiting mode. See below for a thread dump of one of the threads (they are all doing the same thing, so posting a whole thread dump should not be necessary). All of the nio threads appear to be waiting on the same lock (parking to wait for <7ed51011>).
- We are no where near maxing out the heap space
- We are logging abandoned connections and not seeing anything in the logs regarding abandoned connections.
- There are absolutely no errors in any of the tomcat logs. No connection pool exhausted exceptions, out of memory exceptions, etc. NOTHING.

---

```
"http-nio-8080-exec-57" - Thread t@58985
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <7ed51011> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:439)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:360)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at xx.xx.XXXXConnection.getConnection(XXXXConnection.java:62)
    at xx.xx.XX.insert(XX.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    - locked <6aa0c93c> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <242c7551> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

---

We've tried the following:

- We have been monitoring the application with VisualVM and other than seeing all of the threads waiting for a connection during a hang, we aren't seeing anything indicative of a problem.
- We have profiled the application and are not seeing any memory leaks
- We have increased the number of connections in the connection pool,
  but do not see any way we are hitting our maximum (500).
- enabled logging of garbage collection and are only seeing collections taking fractions of a second.

I'm starting to think that this might be something in the network or ISP or something because it is very inconsistent. The application has a pretty consistent load on it at all times and will sometimes run fine for days and then crash several times in a few minutes. Maybe the network is somehow blocking the responses?

Does anyone have any ideas here? This is driving me nuts since we have nothing reporting a problem.

**Update 8/31/2015**

Tomcat is hanging like crazy this morning. It has hung up 7 times in an hour and a half. I've been monitoring the connections on port 8080 and it's staying somewhere around 110. The tomcat sample WAR is still available on the server during the hangs.

** Update 9/7/2015 **

Does anyone see a problem with the resource setup below?

```
<Resource name="jdbc/XX" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="500" 
        minIdle="30" 
        maxIdle="200" 
        maxWait="20000"
        username="username" 
        password="password" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/XX?autoReconnect=true" 
    removeAbandoned="true" 
    removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
    logAbandoned="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you manually connect or run a simpler jar from that machine to connect to whatever database you're trying to reach? I once found that I had these problems because of inconsistent connection (the socket itself) due to a network security element killing the connection without notice (so the socket stayed idle but useless)

Comment: I'll check this out on the next hang

Comment: Upgrade. 8.0.3 is hideously old and might actually have some bugs you are hitting. It's status is marked as "beta". Use 8.0.26, the current-latest version.

Comment: My mistake, we are running 8.0.14 not 8.0.3. Original question has been edited to correct this.

Comment: Also, during a hang other applications are still available on the server. We recently had our connections set to 500 and it randomly hung twice in ten minutes. And this was after being stable for more than 72 hours.

Comment: The resource setup is missing the [factory attribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Inside_the_Apache_Tomcat_Container). Also `autoReconnect=true` is a bad idea when a connection pool is used because that is what the pool does.

Comment: Adding the factory attribute and removing 'autoReconnect=true' caused a ton of "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" errors and then ultimately "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction" errors.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? seeing similar behavior

Comment: did you able to resolve this? facing similar issue

Comment: any luck yet? same case happening

Comment: Same issue here with 8.5.53:
`java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)`
`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:594)`
...
`org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)`